# how to use live and trigger together?

Tags: jquery

I am loading some content via Ajax. After the load completes I want to trigger a `click` event on an anchor element. But this doesn't seem to work. How can I use `trigger` and `live` together?

Comment: what did you try? sample code?

Comment: _As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated._ [jQuery API / .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) Because of this you should not use it in future projects, and something that needs to be rewritten is future project. You should use `.on()` instead. [jQuery API / .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @Sampo Assuming, of course, that you're **using** jQuery 1.7 or later.

Comment: Yes i m using version 1.7.1 @Mihai : i am using this code $(".perm-tabs a[class='active']").trigger("click"); and i dont know how to use live and trigger together somethig like this $(".perm-tabs a[class='active']").live(trigger("click")) ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could trigger it like this:

```
<div id="test">CLICK</div>​
```

---

```
$('#test').live('click', function() {
    window.alert("works");            
});

$(document).trigger({ 
    type:   'click',
    target: $('#test')[0]
});
```

​
Basically, live handlers bind to the document element, so that's where you need to send the event

Comment: Something happened but i think it doesnt work properly for me :(

Comment: I used this code and can see alert saying "works" but i have <a href="#/users/list_users" class="active">Users</a> on click event broesers url should contain "#/users/list_users" this but it doesnt seem to adding it

Comment: In the click handler, you could try document.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');

Comment: If target element is single then it worked, but i put array of element it doesn't. Please guide.

Comment: You'd need to get the array of elements and then loop over them, calling trigger on each

Answer (score 4):

**BIND LIVE EVENTS:**

```
$('PARENT_OF_SOME_ELEMENT').on('EVENT_NAME', 'SOME_ELEMENT', function() {

    // SOME_ELEMENT will be the target

});
```

or using delegate();

```
$('PARENT_OF_SOME_ELEMENT').delegate('SOME_ELEMENT', 'EVENT_NAME', function() {

    // SOME_ELEMENT will be the target

});
```

**TO TRIGGER:**

```
$('SOME_ELEMENT').EVENT_NAME(); //eg. $('SOME_ELEMENT').click();
```

or

```
$('SOME_ELEMENT').trigger('EVENT_NAME'); //eg. $('SOME_ELEMENT').trigger('click');
```

**TO TRIGGER AN EVENT WITHIN AN EVENT**

```
$('AN_EVENT_HOLDER').EVENT_NAME(function() {

   $('SOME_ELEMENT').EVENT_NAME();  // or $('SOME_ELEMENT').trigger('EVENT_NAME'); as illustrated above

});
```

for example

```
$('.i_have_an_event').on('click', function() {
   $('SOME_ELEMENT').click();
});
```

***NOTE***

1. Here `SOME_ELEMENT` and `PARENT_OF_SOME_ELEMENT` are valid selectors.
2. Don't use `.live()` because it has been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

As for `.live()` method is deprecated from jQ 1.6.8 use the `.on()` method:

```
$(document).on('click','a.myAnchor', function(){
    // do your stuff
});

$('#yourElement').on('click', function(){
  $('a.myAnchor').click(); // trigger the dynamically created 'anchor' stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('<parent element selector>').on('click', '<target element selector>', function () {
        // do your stuff
        $('<anchor selector>').trigger('click'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('a#achTest').live('click', function(){
 // some code
});

$('a#achTest').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way that works for me.

```
$('#test').live('click', function() {
    alert("It works!");            
});

$('#test')[0].click();
```

**The important part here is:**

```
$('#test')[0].click();
```